# matplotlib savefig causing a segmentation violation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, segmentation-fault, save

I'm trying to plot some data using **matplotlib**

```
 def _draw_plot(self, iou_values: np.array, parameters, title: str, file_path: str) -> None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=3, figsize=(16, 9), dpi=360, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

        ax.hist(x=iou_values, bins=all_bins[0], facecolor="#FF0000", alpha=0.5, label="Bad IoU", linewidth=1,
                 edgecolor='black')

        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))
        ax.set_xlim(0, 1)

        ax.figure.savefig(file_path, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
        plt.clf()
```

this code is called by an API endpoint. when there are multiple requests at the same time to this endpoint I get this error

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

and the program stops executing.
The issue is in this line

```
        ax.figure.savefig(file_path, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
```

because when I try to comment on this line the issue does not appear

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: are you perhaps trying to write to the same file at the same time from multiple processes? You should make sure that each instance is writing to a different `file_path` or wait until the previous process is finished

Comment: no, every time this function is called it is provided by a unique output path. Moreover, I can't wait for the other process to be finished because the API runs a background task and if I change that the user has to wait a long time until the processing is finished which is not convenient.

Comment: ok, well the code you have given should work fine; for anyone to help diagnose your problem you will need to provide more details about how the function is being called from the API

Comment: after doing some debugging and reading some documentation I found out that `BackgroundTasks` in `FastAPI` actually creates a **thread** of a process that's why different threads have access to the same variable pool (memory) and while there is no mutex to control access to variable common in both thread that's why it can happen that 2 threads access the variable `ax.figure.savefig`  without having the right to. The better solution is to use mutex which I'm not familiar with or use `multiprocessing` which does not share the same memory